# Alert and prompt not working even after function is called

Tags: javascript, alert, prompt

I'm creating a game that generates a random color which the user must guess. This is the first part but when I try to check the page only the onload message displays. I turned off the pop up blocker. I called the function but still nothing.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head> 
    <title>Guess the Color Assignment 2 Part 1</title>      
</head>     

<body onload="do_game()">
<script type="javascript/text">
    var target_index;
    var guess_input_text= "none";
    var guess_input;
    var finished = false;
    var guess = 1;
    var colors=["blue","yellow","red","green","brown","black"];
    colors= colors.sort();      

    function do_game () {

        var random_number = (Math.random() * (colors.length-0)) + 0;
        var random_number_integer = Math.floor(random_number);
        target_index= random_number_integer;
        var target = String(colors[random_number_integer]);
        alert("" + target);     

        while (!finished) {
          guess_input_text = prompt("I am thinking of one of these colors: \n\n" +
                                colors.join(",") + "\n\n What color am I thinking of?");

          guess_input = colors.indexOf(guess_input_text);
          guess += 1;
          finished = check_guess();
        }           
    }       
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You never call your function.

Comment: As an aside, in the line `var target = String(colors[random_number_integer]);` you don't need to use `String()` because the values in the array are already strings.

Answer (score 1):

Your game works but you need to call a `do_game()` function to start it. Also `check_guess()` function is not defined

Comment: Thanks but I added do_game(); but the alerts still don't display

Comment: Thanks. Not sure what's going on with my computer. Thanks for the link